# Divider of items in RecyclerView's vertical list isn't showing up

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm creating RecyclerList for my application and need to set the most simple dividers between list-items. To achieve this I've decided to use DividerItemDecoration class from android.support.v7.widget package.
Here goes the code snippet for this:

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
            layoutManager.getOrientation());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
```

My problem is that there is no divider to appear on a screen of app (I'm testing it on phone with API 18). So, I need a help to define where I'm going wrong and how can I solve my problem. Below I post the full Activity-code with described RecyclerView:

public class GroupsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private GroupsVcAdapter adapter;
private GroupsViewModel mGroupsViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_groups);
    //Creating of toolbar with title Add Group
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_groups);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
    //Enable Up Button
    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //RecyclerView containing the list of groups with sound icons
    adapter = new GroupsVcAdapter(this);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
            layoutManager.getOrientation());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    //Using ViewModel to observe GroupVc data
    mGroupsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GroupsViewModel.class);
    mGroupsViewModel.getAllGroups().observe(this, new Observer<List<GroupVc>>() {

        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<GroupVc> groupVcs) {
            adapter.setGroupsVc(groupVcs);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've found the decision. This code works the way I like:

```
adapter = new GroupsVcAdapter(this);
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
            layoutManager.getOrientation());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```